# aws eks command not recognized using Jenkins pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, kubernetes

I have created a EC2 instance where Jenkins is running connected to my GitHub account. The following are the two steps of my Jenkins pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Kubernetes cluster') {
            steps {
                withAWS(region:'us-west-2', credentials:'aws-kubernetes') {
                    sh '''
                    if [ ! aws cloudformation describe-stacks --region us-west-2 --stack-name eksctl-EmaJarK8sCluster-cluster ] ; then

                        if [ ! aws cloudformation describe-stacks --region us-west-2 --stack-name eksctl-EmaJarK8sCluster-nodegroup-standard-workers ] ; then

                            eksctl create cluster \
                            --name EmaJarK8sCluster \
                            --version 1.13 \
                            --nodegroup-name standard-workers \
                            --node-type t2.small \
                            --nodes 2 \
                            --nodes-min 1 \
                            --nodes-max 3 \
                            --node-ami auto \
                            --region us-west-2 \
                            --zones us-west-2a \
                            --zones us-west-2b \
                            --zones us-west-2c \

                        fi

                    fi
                    '''
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Configuration file cluster') {
            steps {
                withAWS(region:'us-west-2', credentials:'aws-kubernetes') {
                    sh '''
                        aws eks --region us-west-2 update-kubeconfig --name EmaJarK8sCluster
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first step creates a Kubernetes cluster if it doesn't exist, the second one creates a configuration file for that cluster. This step works pretty well and creates two cloudformation stacks and one EC2 machine where the Kubernetes cluster is running.

The second stage fails with the following error:

```
Invalid choice: 'eks', maybe you meant:

  * es
```

After reading a couple of tutorial I've found out that I needed to update `awscli` to version `1.18.57` in order to have the `eks` command available. So I've logged into my Jenkins machine (not the one dedicated to the k8s cluster) ad I've update the `awscli`. 
Unfortunately this is not enough. I still get the same error. I can run the command manually into Jenkins the machine but, for some reason, I cannot run it via Jenkins pipeline.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the full path to the `aws` command? Also add `which aws` and `aws --version` to the second stage script, and confirm that output.

Comment: @RodrigoM Ok, is probably the wrong machine because the path is `/usr/bin/aws` and the version is `aws-cli/1.14.44`

Comment: Looks like it. Also run `hostname` to confirm the actual machine you are running on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the solutions provided didn't work for me. My goal was to setup an machine where I could run a Kubernetes environment in order to implement a blue/green deployment. The deployment had to be handled using Jenkins so I had to create a dedicated machine for Jenkins itself.

I followed this guide to set up all the dependencies:
https://medium.com/faun/learning-kubernetes-by-doing-part-1-setting-up-eks-in-aws-50dcf7a76247

The mistake that I made before was to install all those dependencies using `brew`. This caused many problems and polluted my PATH environment variable. I solved it terminating the machine and creating a new instance. In this case I installed the dependencies manually or using apt-get.

The resources I had to install:

- AWS CLI
- IAM-AWS-AUTHENTICATOR
- Docker
- eksctl

A couple of notes:

- Be sure to install eksctl version 0.19.0 as reported [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-eksctl.html)
- If you get the error `"aws-iam-authenticator": executable file not found in $PATH` be sure to install `aws-iam-authenticator` following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-aws-iam-authenticator.html) guide

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the full path to the `aws` command? Also add `which aws` and `aws --version` to the second stage script, and confirm that output.

The above should highlight the actual path of the command, and the current version. Correct your configuration as needed.

Comment: Ok, pretty weird. They are running on the same machine (same private ip) same directory `/usr/bin` but the version is different.

Comment: Whats more likely is you have two installs. And the environment is different is each process. Are sure that both processes are running under the same user? What user do you use to login via SSH and what user do you use to run Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

Are you updated `jenkins` agents?

If not:

[Upgrading Windows Service Wrapper](https://github.com/jenkinsci/windows-slave-installer-module#upgrading-old-agents)

> 1. Upgrade Jenkins to the version, which provides this module
> 2. Jenkins is expected to automatically upgrade `jenkins-slave.exe` executables
> 3. If the upgrade happens, you should be able to see the message in the `Agent log` in Jenkins Web UI
> 4. Once upgrade is done, the changes will be applied on the next Windows service restart